# Footer will not stay at bottom of page

Tags: html, css

My footer will not stay at the bottom of the page. Now when I use `position: fixed;` or `position: absolute;`, It says at the bottom of the browser and not the page. So I want it to make it stay at the bottom of the webpage, but also stays below the content.

I tried adding `height: 100%;` to my wrapper (my footer is outside my wrapper) and it didn't work. I also just tried adding the sticky footer and it didn't work, but I left that part in my jsfiddle also.

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PfVFd/

Now it seems to work with a small screen (like the result window on jsfiddle), but on a 1080 resolution, it doesn't work so here's my website also: http: http://erraticfox.com/about.html

Answer (score 4):

you should read Ryan documentation about the sticky footer, everything is on: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

To complete my previous answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/PfVFd/1/

You should have position: fixed

```
footer {
line-height: 100px;
position: fixed;
background: rgba(28, 32, 36, 1);
bottom:0px;
width: 100%;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
height: 100px;
text-align: center; }
```

Comment: The footer still scrolls in front of the content.

Answer (score 3):

Make position:absolute and bottom:0px

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
  box-sizing:         border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}


footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>This footer will always be positioned at the bottom of the page, but <strong>not fixed</strong>.</footer>
```